# Firebase Authentication createUserWithEmailAndPassword fails on physical devices with variable for email

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When using createUserWithEmailAndPassword there are two issues,

1. It works on the Emulator, but not in debug mode on a physical device
2. To make it work on a physical device I can hardcode a string for the email portion, even if it is saved into a variable. It breaks when getting the email from an EditText, but I have used Log.d() to confirm that the string is exactly the same before the creation method is called.

This works

```
    final String sEmail = "ExampleEmail@gmail.com";
            final String sPassword = password.getText().toString();
            final String sDisplayName = displayName.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Credentials:Email", sEmail);
            Log.d("Credentials:Password", sPassword);
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(sEmail,sPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        /*UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(sDisplayName).build();
                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                        mAuth.signOut();*/
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserLogin.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }else{
                        Toast creationFailed = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Creation Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        creationFailed.show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

This does not.

```
    final String sEmail = email.getText().toString();
            final String sPassword = password.getText().toString();
            final String sDisplayName = displayName.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Credentials:Email", sEmail);
            Log.d("Credentials:Password", sPassword);
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(sEmail,sPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        /*UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(sDisplayName).build();
                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                        mAuth.signOut();*/
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserLogin.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }else{
                        Toast creationFailed = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Creation Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        creationFailed.show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is the error message

```
    2019-01-14 13:44:48.298 3217-16541/? E/Volley: [1455] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyCTfahJaTfOSAOdY7_pIN27-BGQgFlORnE
```

Note that for some reason, the second one that does not work will work on an emulated device. I expect the second to create the account, but it just fails.

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176602/firebase-authentication-createuserwithemailandpassword-fails-on-physical-devices) questions.

Comment: Pls, post logcat erro

Comment: @AlexMamo this is not a duplicate question as I have found a different location of the error. I am encountering the same issue, but I have narrowed down the error and figure the error is not what I originally assumed it to be.

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa

        2019-01-14 13:44:48.298 3217-16541/? E/Volley: [1455] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyCTfahJaTfOSAOdY7_pIN27-BGQgFlORnE

Comment: post logcat erro inside question

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa done.

Comment: since when Firebase uses Volley? and this is a duplicate, because adding more information to the other question would have been sufficient, to reflect the current situation. please remove one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Authentication createUserWithEmailAndPassword fails on physical devices, but not emulated devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176602/firebase-authentication-createuserwithemailandpassword-fails-on-physical-devices)

Comment: Get the error from the task in the else task dot get error or something like that

Comment: @cutiko What? Can you read over what you said it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I don't know? It's just the error that appears over and over again when I click the button that would trigger the action.

Comment: did your input as email format? @JeremyO'Handley

Comment: @Zuhrain can you submit that as a separate answer so I can accept it for you? I'm not sure why that worked, because it was working without it on an emulated device, but not on physical ones, but I'm glad it does, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that your input is not email type. Please keep in mind that it need email type.

Make a method to check email valid

```
   //Check email valid
    boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Then apply to your part.

```
        //Check email valid
        if (!isEmailValid(email.getText().toString())) {
            email.setError("Not email type");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
```

About your toast, maybe it would be better if you put like this. So, you can know what error that you faced.

```
else {             
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am very new to Android and Firebase and your short answer has offered me a lot of information, thank you!

Comment: @JeremyO'Handley You're welcome. Feel free to ask question next time. You are welcome here.